# Slider desaparece cuando me logueo en la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap, angular

Tengo un problema con un **slider de una plantilla** que tiene bootstrap en su version 3.3.7. Sucede que cuando me logueo en la página mediante los navegadores(mozilla, chrome y edge) los productos y fotografias que provienen de la base de datos desaparecen y solo aparecen cuando vuelvo a **recargar la pagina manualmente**. **¿Cual puede ser la causa de este problema?**

El sistema esta funcionando sobre la version **6 de angular** y esta enlazado a un sistema backend desarrollado en Django...

Este es el código del Slider:

```
<ng-container>
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-10 col-xs-6">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane active">
      <div class="product-slider  product-slider1">
        <div class="wrap-item" data-pagination="false" data-navigation="true" data-itemscustom="[[0,1],[768,2],[1024,3],[1200,4]]">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let prod of productFinal">
            <div class="item-product item-product1 style2 text-center">
              <div class="product-thumb">
                <a href="detail.html" class="product-thumb-link rotate-thumb">
                  <img src="{{prod.images}}" alt="">
                  <img src="{{prod.images}}" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="quick-view.html" class="quickview-link fancybox fancybox.iframe"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="product-info">
                <h3 class="product-title"><a href="detail.html">{{prod.name_product}}</a></h3>
                <div class="product-price">
                  <ins class="color"><span>€30.000</span></ins>
                </div>
                <div class="product-rate">
                  <div class="product-rating" style="width:100%"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-extra-link">
                  <a href="#" class="wishlist-link"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Wishlist</span></a>
                  <a href="#" class="addcart-link">Add to cart</a>
                  <a href="#" class="compare-link"><i class="fa fa-compress" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Compare</span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Algunas capturas de pantalla del problema:
[image: Antes de recargar la página]

[image: Después de recargar la página]

Este es el código del componente:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {IProductAll} from '../shared/models/IProductAll';
import {IProduct} from '../shared/models/IProduct';
import {ProductService} from '../services/product/product.service';
import {CategoriesService} from '../services/categories/categories.service';
import {BrandsService} from '../services/brands/brands.service';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

formSearch: FormGroup;
public url: SafeUrl;
public productFinal: IProductAll[] = [];
subscriptions: Subscription;
products: IProductAll[] = [];
productsImages: IProduct[] = [];
AllImages: IProduct[] = [];
constructor(private _productService: ProductService, private 
_categorieService: CategoriesService, private _brandService: BrandsService, 
private translate: TranslateService) {
   translate.setDefaultLang('es');
}
ngOnInit() {

this.getCategories();

this.formSearch = new FormGroup({
  search: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
});
this.subscriptions = this._productService.getProducts().subscribe(response => {
  this.products.push(...response);
  this.subscriptions = this._productService.getImagesAll().subscribe(r => {
    this.productsImages.push(...r.filter(rsp => rsp.image = rsp.image.replace(/^/, `${environment.apiUrl}`)));
    for (let j = 0; j < this.products.length; j++) {
      for (let p = 0; p < this.productsImages.length; p++) {
        if (this.productsImages[p].product_id === this.products[j].id_product) {
          this.AllImages.push(this.productsImages[p]);
          this.products[j].images = this.productsImages[p].image;
        }
      }
      const filter = this.AllImages.filter(rsp => rsp.product_id === this.products[j].id_product);
      this.products[j].imagesAll = filter;
    }
  });

  this.productFinal = this.products;
     console.log(this.productFinal);
  });
 }useLanguage(languaje: string) {
    this.translate.use(languaje);
 }getCategories() {
  this.subscriptions = 
  this._categorieService.getCategories().subscribe(response => {
     console.log(response);
   });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Como es el código del controlador del componente?

Comment: ok, ya actuaicé la pregunta con el código del componente

Comment: Y cuando haces el login se envía a otra ruta? digo porque capaz y se está mandando al router a que muestre otra página. Coloca el código de inicio de sesión a ver.

Comment: no, a la misma, solo que el slider de la vista como se ve en las imagenes no aparece a no ser que recargue la ruta manualmente

Comment: Sucede que todo lo que tienes en el `ngOnInit` no se está realizando completamente antes de que la vista haga su render, es decir, la vista carga antes que todo el `suscribe` que haces para armar el slider en el controlador. Lo que podrías hacer es que al hacer el login, "repartir" el render de los elementos y consultas entre el componente del login y el del home.

Te recomiendo además que utilices `async`-`await` para evitar que se ejecute código antes que el slider se arme completamente.